# Java to VB.NET AES Encryption

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption

I have this code here which I'm having difficulty converting to VB.NET and hoping someone who give me a hand with it.

I'm having difficulty with the part on the cipher - I have tried Googling but was unable to find a clear resource explaining it in simple terms. (I don't know how to proceed with it as it seems there's no equivalent for it??)

I have almost no knowledge of java hence am trying to google and find out what each part means and convert it after. Hope someone would be able to point me in the right direction!

```
 public static byte[] decryptPDF(String password, String filePath) {
    try {
        byte[] headerSaltAndCipherText = Base64.decode(IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)), "UTF-8").toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), 0);
        byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(headerSaltAndCipherText, 8, 16);
        byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(headerSaltAndCipherText, 16, headerSaltAndCipherText.length);
        Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[][] keyAndIV = EVP_BytesToKey(32, aesCBC.getBlockSize(), MessageDigest.getInstance(CommonUtils.MD5_INSTANCE), salt, password.getBytes("UTF-8"), 1);
        aesCBC.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[0], "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[1]));
        return aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e4) {
        e4.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e5) {
        e5.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e6) {
        e6.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e7) {
        e7.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I've tried so far is...

```
Public Shared Function decryptPDF(ByVal password As String, ByVal fileAsString As String) As Byte()
    Try
        Dim headerSaltAndCipherText() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(fileAsString)
        Dim salt() As Byte = headerSaltAndCipherText.Skip(7).Take(8)
        Dim encrypted() As Byte = headerSaltAndCipherText.Skip(15).Take(headerSaltAndCipherText.Length)
        Dim aesCBC As Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        Dim keyAndIV() As Byte = EVP_BytesToKey(32, aesCBC.getBlockSize, MessageDigest.getInstance(CommonUtils.MD5_INSTANCE), salt, password.getBytes("UTF-8"), 1)
        aesCBC.init(2, New SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV(0), "AES"), New IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV(1)))
        Return aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted)

    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: A quick google search reports 12,800 hits on this site alone.  How do they not work for you?

Comment: Obviously i tried using those but they didn't work, and if you even read the question i'm asking about the Cipher part??? There was only one result from VBForums talking about openSSL-VB.NET rijndael that was able to partially give some hint but it had some wrong padding/alignment.

Comment: How exactly is it *obvious* to us?  That first snippet is c# not java, so it is also not clear what the heck java has to do with this.   Rather than all that, since the source appears to be a file, you could use a `CrytoStream` which might be easier.

Comment: @Plutonix Uhm.  The first code excerpt is definitely Java.

Comment: Why does the code you have not work?  Provide expected input and output pairs and the result you are actually getting.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  Still, why does the VB code need to match it unless you have 2 pieces sharing somehow.  The key element is not how something else decrypts it, but how it was encrypted since that is what you want to undo.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
Public Shared Function decryptPDF(ByVal password As String, ByVal filePath As String) As Byte()
        Try 
            Dim headerSaltAndCipherText() As Byte = Base64.decode(IOUtils.toString(New FileInputStream(New File(filePath)), "UTF-8").toString.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0)
            Dim salt() As Byte = Arrays.copyOfRange(headerSaltAndCipherText, 8, 16)
            Dim encrypted() As Byte = Arrays.copyOfRange(headerSaltAndCipherText, 16, headerSaltAndCipherText.length)
            Dim aesCBC As Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
            Dim keyAndIV(,) As Byte = EVP_BytesToKey(32, aesCBC.getBlockSize, MessageDigest.getInstance(CommonUtils.MD5_INSTANCE), salt, password.getBytes("UTF-8"), 1)
            aesCBC.init(2, New SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV(0), "AES"), New IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV(1)))
            Return aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted)
        Catch e As IOException
            e.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        Catch e2 As NoSuchPaddingException
            e2.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        Catch e3 As InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            e3.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        Catch e4 As NoSuchAlgorithmException
            e4.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        Catch e5 As IllegalBlockSizeException
            e5.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        Catch e6 As BadPaddingException
            e6.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        Catch e7 As InvalidKeyException
            e7.printStackTrace
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: This is just a direct conversion from Java. It won't work. Most of the types and methods being used in that code don't exists in .NET.